# Django REST Framework returns 403 instead of 405

Tags: python, http, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet which has an action decorated method

```
@action(
        methods=['get'],
        detail=False,
        url_path='logout',
        url_name='logout',
        authentication_classes=(TokenAuthentication,),
        permission_classes=(UsersPermissions,),
        serializer_class=UserSerializer
    )
def logout(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
    ...
```

When I HTTP GET to /logout/ it works fine.
But when I POST to it instead of throwing 405 it goes through permissions with `view.action = None` and throws 403.
Checking `view.action` and throwing 405 in permissions sounds bad.

Adding *urls.py* here:

```
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=True)

router.register('users', views.UsersViewSet, basename='users')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

*logout* is in *UsersViewSet*

Comment: How do you register this view ? It is viewset ?

Comment: The problem is that after applying action to a method, when i POST to /logout APIView dispatches request and sets my ModelViewSet to dispatch POST /logout, which after all causes view.action to be None and because of that my permissions fail.  I need to my ModelViewSet throw MethodNotAllowed() on POSTing to /logout

Comment: It seems like a bug tbh

Comment: Please update your question with router and urls.py file

Comment: @monio, it is nothing extraordinary, but i did add it

Comment: Add `UsersPermissions` class.